# How to push function to vector with their parameters in c++14?

Tags: vector, c++14, googletest

I want to have a vector from functions. I want to write series of test for my software. At first I need to implement a class(for example `TestClass`) for running the functions for example in [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest). I want in my other classes send their functions and parameters to TestClass for test.

So in short i need these :

1. A vector of functions
2. How to send the input parameters to `TestClass`?
3. How to send the grand truth output as parameter to `TestClass`?

In forward I appreciate your supports.

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: Hint: if you have a `std::vector<std::function<bool()>> tests`, you can `bool result = std::all_of(tests.begin(), tests.end(), [](auto & test) { return test(); });`

Comment: Clarification: Are you wanting to send one set of parameters to all the tests in the list, or has each test got different parameters?